# How to test Guice Singleton?

Tags: java, unit-testing, singleton, module, guice

Guice Singletons are weird for me

First I thought that

```
IService ser = Guice.createInjector().getInstance(IService.class);
System.out.println("ser=" + ser);
ser = Guice.createInjector().getInstance(IService.class);
System.out.println("ser=" + ser);
```

will work as singleton, but it returns

```
ser=Service2@1975b59
ser=Service2@1f934ad
```

its ok, it doesnt have to be easy.

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector();
IService ser = injector.getInstance(IService.class);
System.out.println("ser=" + ser);
ser = injector.getInstance(IService.class);
System.out.println("ser=" + ser);
```

works as singleton

```
ser=Service2@1975b59
ser=Service2@1975b59
```

So i need to have static field with Injector(Singleton for Singletons)

how do i pass to it Module for testing?

Comment: I disagree with the premise of your question! Have you read the Guice user's guide?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When using Guice, you should create exactly one injector per JVM. Usually you'll create it in your application's entry point (ie. in your `public static void main` method). If you call `createInjector` multiple times in your application, you may be using Guice wrong!

Singletons are instance-per-injector. Note that this is *not* instance-per-JVM. The best way to obtain a reference to a singleton is to be injected with it. The other way is to ask the one and only injector instance to give it to you.

Comment: Let's say that I need two injectors in my jvm, will that get me in trouble?

Comment: Can you have multiple createInjector for different modules?

Comment: To those asking about creating multiple injectors and different modules yes you can. I have a unique situation where i am integrating with legacy code and no DI available. Each of my addons to the system has its own Injector. If i need a singleton across injectors i create a oldschool singleton module where my module provides the singleton classes through its own injector.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to do a little more testing (and reading) before making wild, inaccurate accusations like that. I'm using Guice to manage my singleton instances just fine.

What do your module bindings look like? The singleton pattern in the GoF is simply a way of ensuring that there is one instance of a class, but the use of `static` makes it actually a bad choice. The need for a singleton is that there is only one instance of a class available while the application is running.

The following is all that is needed to create a singleton instance using Guice:

```
public class myModule extends AbstractModule {
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Service.class).to(ServiceImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

When you ask Guice to give you the instance, you'll get the same instance unless you do some unique scoping yourself. Per default, the singleton will be for the current `Injector` instance.

Comment: I disagree, I thought Guice statically hold references(since they always create new injector in the video on the page)

Comment: Fact is that that is not how Guice works. Guice is only involved in the process of object creation and wiring up your object dependency graph. Once that happens, it sorta disappears. There are no "static" singletons - it's just the same object reference passed around to the different instances that use it or need it. The static notion was a way of doing it using the language directly, DI addresses that "shortcoming" of the language by allowing the same thing, just without the cost of using static state.

Comment: What he said is not inaccurate. Singletons are not shared between injectors. If you create two separate injectors and request a singleton scoped object from either of them they will be different objects. Also your last statement is incorrect Per default the singleton will be for the current Injector instance not vm instance.